# por que esta operación relacional da error en pandas

Tags: python, pandas

tengo un archivo csv con datos históricos de una liga de futbol

```
import pandas as pd
archivo = pd.read_csv('liga.csv', sep=',')
dtf = pd.DataFrame(archivo)
```

lo que quiero es comparar los valores de una columna con los de otra, es decir y como ejemplo, quiero saber los partidos que ha ganado el arsenal como local, entonces tengo este dataframe

```
hometeam awayteam ftr whd
arsenal  everton  D   4.2
...
```

este es el codigo que da error en python3

```
x=0
if dtf.HomeTeam == 'Arsenal' and dtf.FTR == 'A':
    x+=1
print(x)
```

el error de salida

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
> a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Creo que lo que estás intentando hacer es más complejo de lo que crees. Lo que dices en esa condición es: "Por cada valor de la columna `HomeTeam` devuelveme `True` o `False` si el valor es igual a *Arsenal*" y luego quieres comparar eso que es un vector de datos con lo que hay despues del `and` " por cada valor en la columna `FTR` devuelveme `True` o `False` si el valor es igual a *A*" Lo que estás haciendo es comparar dos Series de `True` y `False` lo cual no es posible y por eso te lanza el error.

Comment: DIcho lo anterior, deberías poner un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) del `DataFrame` que tienes, para que podamos trabajar con él. Es decir, crear un DataFrame en código que se pueda copiar facilmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondiendo directamente a la pregunta del título:

> por que esta operación relacional da error en pandas

y para entender qué significa el críptico mensaje de pandas:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

hay que explicar que en Python los operadores `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`, `==` y `!=` son todos redefinibles, pero los operadores `and`, `or` y `not` no lo son. Esto tiene su importancia en el caso que nos ocupa.

Pandas ha redefinido los operadores de comparación para que funcionen con Series (columnas) y para que, en lugar de retornar `True` o `False`, retornen una serie (una columna) de booleanos.

Así cuando haces `dtf.HomeTeam == 'Arsenal'` debido a esa redefinición hecha por Pandas, el resultado de la comparación es **una columna** llena de booleanos, en el que habrá  `True` en las filas que `HomeTeam` sea 'Arsenal' y `False` en las filas en que no lo sea. Hasta aquí bien.

Por otro lado podrías pensar que `dtf.FTR == 'A'` hace lo mismo produciendo otra columna de booleanos y que finalmente `and` realiza la operación 'Y' entre ambas columnas, produciendo como resultado otra columna de booleanos con `True` sólo en las posiciones en las que ambas series tenían `True`.

Por desgracia eso no es así porque, como he dicho , **`and` no puede ser redefinido** y por tanto sigue siendo el operador python "normal". Si `and` pudiera redefinirse, sin duda Pandas lo habría hecho para que pudiera operar con Series y de ese modo tu expresión habría funcionado.

### Qué está ocurriendo entonces

La redefinición de `==` se hace implementando en una clase el método `__eq__()`, de modo que cuando haces `a == b` en realidad Python invoca `a.__eq__(b)`.

Eso es lo que ocurre con tu dataframe, y por tanto `dtf.HomeTeam == 'Arsenal'` en realidad consiste en ejecutar `dft.HomeTeam.__eq__('Arsenal')`. La condición de tu `if` se ve entonces así:

```
dtf.HomeTea.__eq__('Arsenal') and dtf.FTR.__eq__('A')
```

Por tanto Python ejecuta cada uno de esos métodos, obtiene dos columnas de booleanos y se encuentra entonces con que tiene que evaluar algo como:

```
columna_booleanos_1 and columna_booleanos_2
```

El operador `and` sólo sabe comparar entre sí un booleano con otro. Cuando se encuentra con un tipo que no es booleano (como `columna_booleanos_1` por ejemplo), intentará convertirlo en un booleano, por lo que en realidad se intentará lo siguiente:

```
bool(columna_booleanos_1) and bool(columna_booleanos_2)
```

La función `bool` se resuelve invocando el método `__bool__` de esos objetos, por lo que equivale a:

```
columna_booleanos_1.__bool__() and columna_booleanos_2.__bool__()
```

y aquí entra Pandas de nuevo, pues Pandas ha implementado el método `__bool__()` en los objetos de tipo `Series`. Si la implementación de Pandas retornara como resultado `True` o `False`, todo seguiría felizmente, pues `and` hará su trabajo entre dos booleanos.

Pero Pandas se encuentra con una columna llena de `True` y `False` y se le pide convertirla en un único valor, `True` o `False`. ¿Cuál debería ser el resultado? Si toda la columna estuviera llena de `True` parece que el resultado debería ser `True`, pero ¿y si contiene algún `False`? No está claro qué se debería hacer en ese caso. De modo que de forma general Pandas renuncia a convertir una columna en un booleano, y nos da su error (que ahora voy a traducir):

> El valor booleano de una Serie es ambiguo. Debes usar a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any(), o a.all()

Esos son métodos que están claramente definidos para producir un solo booleano como resultado ante una serie de ellos. Por ejemplo `a.all()` dará `True` sólo si *todos* son `True`, mientras que `a.any()` dará `True` con tal de que *al menos* uno de ellos sea `True`.

### Cómo arreglarlo

En el caso en que lo que realmente quisieras fuera una columna con `True` en aquellos lugares en que ambas eran `True`, es decir la operación `and` *elemento a elemento* entre ambas columnas, para ese caso puedes utilizar el operador `&` en lugar de `and`.

El operador `&` forma parte del lenguaje python, y está inicialmente pensado como una operación aritmético-lógica entre enteros (lo que se llama el *bitwise and*, que en C sería también el operador `&`). Sin embargo, a diferencia de `and`, **el operador `&` es redefinible** y Pandas lo ha redefinido para que haga justo lo que aquí necesitamos: una operación lógica entre columnas.

Por tanto habría que reescribir tu condición así:

```
(dtf.HomeTeam == 'Arsenal') & (dtf.FTR == 'A')
```

En este caso hay que utilizar paréntesis alrededor de las comparaciones, porque el operador `&` tiene más precedencia que el operador `==`.

El resultado de esa condición es una columna de booleanos. Puedes obtener cuántos `True` hay en esa columna si simplemente calculas la suma (ya que cuando python suma booleanos los trata como 1 y 0).

Es decir:

```
x = sum((dtf.HomeTeam == 'Arsenal') & (dtf.FTR == 'A'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# filtrar filas específicas en Pandas desde un DataFrame

# se debe para OR | y para AND &
    
dtf [ ( dtf [ 'hometeam' ] == 'Arsenal' ) & ( dtf [ 'ftr' ] == 'A' ) ]
```

Comment: Si explicaras el código otros podriamos aprender algo más de Pandas. Un trozo de código sin explicación no enseña ni educa.